# Webmin Database Permissions

Tags: database, permissions, webmin

Is there a way that I can set user permissions in webmin/vitrualmin so that only certain databases show up.

I've created a Mysql user and set their permissions so that they can perform actions against the given databse.  However when they log in (to MySQL, connecting via php for example) they can see all databases on the server not just theirs.

Is there a way to stop this?

Regards.

Comment: if i log into phpmyadmin with one of my virtualmin account users all i see is their db's, is yours any different ?

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem in Webmin.

But I manage to fix it in Webmin.

You have to check in "*User Permissions*" the column "*Permission*". I change "*All*" to "*None*".

You give the access after in "Database Permissions" to the database.

Hope this helps !